# Isomorphism between functors of rings and their completions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $(Loc/k)$ be the category of local $k$-algebras $R$ with residual field $k$ such that the tangent space $T_R=Hom(m_R/m_R^2,-)$ is a finite dimensional vector space, where $m_R$ is the maximal ideal of $R$. In that category, we denote functor $h_R=Hom(R,-)$, the set of local homomorphisms. Then it’s said that there is a natural isomorphism between $h_R$ and $h_{\hat{R}}$, where $\hat{R}$ is the completion of $R$.

In one way, since local homomorphism maps maximal ideal to maximal ideal, we can deduce $Hom(R/m_R^n,A)$ from $Hom(R,A)$ for any $n$ and $A$, thus $h_R$ deduces $h_{\hat{R}}$. But how do we define the isomorphism in the other direction? Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: If this were true then it would follow that $R\cong \hat{R}$ by Yoneda.

Comment: But the definition of $h_R$ here is a little different from that of representable functor in Yoneda lemma.

Comment: There is a bijection between the homomorphisms $R\to \hat{A}$ and $\hat{R}\to \hat{A}$.